# A particle in a one-dimensional box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

The Question:

---

Consider a particle in a one-dimensional box, i.e. in a potential
$$V(x)=
\begin{cases} 
0 &  \text{ for } 0\leq x \leq L \\
\infty &  \text{ for } x < 0 \text{ and } x > L . 
\end{cases}
$$
Its wave function is a linear superposition of two stationary states and given by
$$\psi(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\left[\sqrt{5}\psi_1(x,t)+i\sqrt{3}\psi_3(x,t)\right].$$
a) Use the stationary eigenstates in this potential (from your lecture notes or from a textbook), and write down $\psi(x,t)$.

Then calculate $|\psi(x,t)|^2.$ Make sure that your result for $|\psi(x,t)|^2.$ is manifestly real (no "$i$" left in there). Recall the relation $exp(i\theta)=cos\theta+isin\theta$.

What is the frequency of the oscillation in $|\psi(x,t)|^2$?

b) Calculate the expectation value of the Hamilton operator $\hat{H}$. Compare it with the energy eigenvalues $E_1$, $E_2$, $E_3$.

c) What is the probability for the particle to be in state $\psi_1$, and what are the probabilities for it to be in states $\psi_2$ and $\psi_3$, respectively?

d) Calculate the expectation values $\langle\hat{x}\rangle$ and $\langle\hat{p}\rangle$.

Is the particle's state stationary? Why, or why not?

---

My Attempt:

---

a) 
As given, in the question each superposed wave function are functions of time, thus the wave functions are of form:
$$\psi_n(x,t)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{l}}sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{l}\right)e^{-\frac{iE_nt}{\hbar}},$$
Where the energy, $E_n$:
$$E_n=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2.$$
By substitution of states n= 1 and 3, and then back into the given superposition equation, we see:
$$\psi(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\left[\sqrt{5}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{l}}sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{l}\right)e^{-\frac{i\hbar\pi ^2t}{2ml^2}}\right)+i\sqrt{3}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{l}}sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}{l}\right)e^{-9\frac{i\hbar\pi^2t}{2ml^2}}\right)\right].$$

Now, to find $|\psi(x,t)|^2,$ we can use the relation $|\psi(x,t)|^2=\psi^*(x,t)\cdot\psi(x,t).$

I am reasonably confident with the maths, here is my answer:
$$\psi(x,t)\cdot\psi^*(x,t)=\frac{5}{4l}sin^2\left(\frac{\pi x}{l}\right)+\frac{3}{4l}sin^2\left(\frac{3\pi x}{l}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2l}sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{l}\right) sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}{l}\right)sin\left(\frac{(E_3-E_1)t}{\hbar}\right)$$

Thus, it is clear that the frequency of oscillation is:$$\frac{(E_3-E_1)t}{\hbar}$$
**My Problem-Part A**-I am unsure on what the frequency of oscillation is actually referring to in this case, if anyone could provide some intuition for this, that'd be great.

---

b)Given the relation: $$<\hat{H}>=\sum_n |c_n|^2E_n,$$
$$<\hat{H}>=\lvert \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{8}}\rvert^2\frac{\hbar^2\pi^2}{2ml^2}+\lvert\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{8}}\rvert^2\frac{9\hbar^2\pi^2}{2ml^2}$$
simplified, this gives:
$$<\hat{H}>=\frac{32\hbar^2\pi^2}{ml^2}.$$
I have been asked to compare this with the eigenstates:
$$E_1=\frac{\hbar^2\pi^2}{2ml^2},$$
$$E_2=\frac{4\hbar^2\pi^2}{2ml^2},$$
$$E_3=\frac{9\hbar^2\pi^2}{2ml^2}.$$
**My problem- part b**
I can see the following
$$64E_1=<\hat{H}>,$$
$$4E_2=<\hat{H}>,$$
$$\frac{64}{9}E_3=<\hat{H}>,$$
But I am struggling to see the relevancy, I think the explanation of this, may also to explain part d

c)I'm not sure where to start with this part

d)$$<x>=\int_0^L|\psi|^2x.dx$$
I have no problem with this integral, I have found the answer to be $\frac{1}{2}l$, which makes sense to me as it is the center point of the 'well'.

Now, to find $<p>$, i can consider:
$$<p>=m\frac{d}{dt}<x>,$$
clearly this leads to $<p>=0$,

**Part d-My Problem**
This is what confuses me, surely its state should be stationary if the velocity is zero, which must be true assuming the particle is not massless. However I feel like I am mis-understanding the definition of its 'state' Also, I vaguely remember my lecturer saying something about this linking with the comparison in part b.

Comment: I think the expectation value of the energy should be between the lowest and highest states: $E_1 < \langle H \rangle < E_3 $, and given that $(5\cdot 1^2 + 3 \cdot 3^2)/8 = 1 \cdot 2^2$, you should find it equal to $E_2$. Check your math. Did you drop a $(1/\sqrt 8)^2$?

Comment: I did miss the factor of $(1/\sqrt{8})^2$, thanks :)

Comment: Part d) must have the time dependent terms included. The $\int \psi_1^* ~\psi_3 ~x~dx$ and vice-versa integrals are not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) When I read the question, I didn't know what was meant by oscillation frequency, but I think you figured it out. There is a time-dependence to the interference term.

(b) Check the math. Have you considered just factoring out $E_1$ in all the terms?

(c) Are you familiar with bra-ket notation? The probability to be in eigenstate $n$ is:

$$ \langle n | \psi \rangle $$

where

$$ |\psi \rangle = \sqrt{\frac 5 8}|1\rangle + i\sqrt{\frac 3 8}|3\rangle$$

and

$$ \langle n|m\rangle \equiv \int{\psi_n(x, t)^*\psi_m(x, t)dx} = \delta_{nm}.$$

It saves a lot MathJax in the long run, and is much clearer.

So you figured out the particle is on average in the middle of the box, but it is not *in* the middle of the box. Likewise with the momentum: it's moving in both directions, but if it had a nonzero mean--it would just leave the box.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I don't understand that notation (never seen it before). If I were looking to find the probability that the particle is in state $\psi_1$ would I just consider $\int_0^l ψ_1(x,t)∗ψ_1(x,t)dx$?

Comment: @George No, that expression is 1, since all eigenstates are normalized. In bra-key notation, the _amplitude is  $\langle 1 | \psi \rangle =  \frac{1} {\sqrt 5} \langle 1 | 1 \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \langle 1 | 3 \rangle $ $ = \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} $, so the probability is that squared (20%). Think of it a projecting $\psi$ onto an orthonormal basis. Note I edited the answer to make the a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I read in a book however, that the probability of finding the particle in any of the eigenstates are the absolute square of the relevant coefficients. Surely this would make the answer: 5/8 for $E_1$ and 3/8 for $E_3$ and 0 for $E_2$?

Comment: @George You are correct. I had the coefficients upside down, and forgot the root 8. I was rushing, and flubbed it big time.